# Mocha tests on focus-related behaviors (Backbone/CoffeeScript app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I have a Backbone app written in CoffeeScript. I'm trying to use Mocha (with Chai and Sinon) to write tests for DOM-related behaviors, but it seems that hidden fixtures (I'm using [js-fixtures](https://github.com/badunk/js-fixtures) now but I've also tried this unsuccessfully with a hidden `'#fixtures'` div) don't register certain DOM-related behaviors which makes testing certain types of DOM-related behaviors (seemingly) impossible.

For example, my main app view has several subviews which are never rendered at the same time: when the app view renders subview A, it remembers the focused element of the currently active subview B (`@_visibleView`), saves that information on subview B, closes the subview B, and then renders subview A.

```
    _rememberFocusedElement: ->
      focusedElement = $ document.activeElement
      if focusedElement
        focusedElementId = focusedElement.attr 'id'
        if focusedElementId
          @_visibleView?.focusedElementId = focusedElementId
```

This works when I test it manually, but when I try to write unit tests for this behavior they fail because I can't set focus (e.g., via `$(selector).focus()`) to an element in a hidden div/iframe. (I have the same issue with functionality which listens for window resize events.)

I thought that if I changed `$ document.activeElement` to `@$ ':focus"` I might get different results, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Here is what the relevant parts of my Mocha (BDD) tests look like. This spec will print `TEXTAREA` to the console and then `undefined`, indicating that there *is* a textarea with id='transcription' but I can't set focus to it.

```
    beforeEach (done) ->
      fixtures.path = 'fixtures'
      callback = =>
        @$fixture = fixtures.window().$ "<div id='js-fixtures-fixture'></div>"
        @appView = new AppView el: @$fixture
        done()

    describe 'GUI stuff', ->
      it 'remembers the currently focused element of a subview', (done) ->
        @appView.mainMenuView.once 'request:formAdd', =>
          @appView._visibleView.$('#transcription').focus()
          console.log @appView._visibleView.$('#transcription').prop 'tagName'
          console.log @appView._visibleView.$(':focus').prop 'tagName'
          done()
        @appView.mainMenuView.trigger 'request:formAdd'
```

Is there any way that I can write unit tests for these types of behaviors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first off let me clarify something: the term "unit test" means man different things to many people.  Often times it becomes synonymous with "any test written using a unit test framework (like Mocha)".  When I use the term "unit test" that's not what I mean: what I mean is a test that tests only a single unit of work (which, in a JS environment, will usually be a single function, but might be a whole class).

Ok, with that out of the way, if you really are trying to unit test your code, you're sort of taking the wrong approach.  A unit test really shouldn't rely on anything outside the context of the function being tested, and so relying on the (external) DOM is where your problem lies.

Let's assume your focus-handling code is in a function called `handleFocus` (I don't know the actual method name). Consider the following test, which I'll write using JavaScript since my CoffeScript is rusty:

```
describe('#handleFocus', function() {
    it('remembers the currently focused element of a subview', function() {
        var setFocusStub = sinon.stub($.fn, 'focus');
        appView._visibleView.handleFocus();
        expect(setFocusStub.calledOnce).to.be(true);
    });
});
```

The above is a bit of an over-simplification, but hopefully it illustrates the point. What you're really trying to check isn't whether the DOM (fake or real) does X; what you're trying check is whether your function does X.  By focusing on that in your test, and relying on a stub that checks whether "X" happened or not, you completely eliminate the need for the DOM to be involved.

Now of course you might wonder: "well great, that helps me in test-land, but how do I know it will work in a real environment?" My answer to that would be that your (probably Selenium-based) *acceptance* tests should cover that sort of thing. Acceptance tests should check whether your overall code works in the real world, while unit tests should ensure that individual pieces of that code work in a fake environment.

The former is great for ensuring your customers don't see bugs, while the latter is great for figuring out exactly where those bugs come from, and for making it possible for you to refactor safely.